# How to get the instance into which the activated object has been injected at activation time?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm trying to utilize `Ninject` to help me build up a possible tree of service classes. I'd like to inject an `ILogger` instance using `InCallScope` so any child service class would use the same logger.

The logger implementation has a property called `RootService`, which would point to the upper-most service class instance which uses the logger. I would use information from it when categorizing logged events according to from which service class it has come from (child classes would not define another "log scope", hence I use `InCallScope`).

Can I fine-tune the `ILogger` Ninject binding so that I could have kind of a callback when the `ILogger` instance is activated, and I had there the instance too, into which it recently got injected? So there I could set the `RootService` property of my logger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's is the `OnActivation` binding extension which is a callback which is executed when `ILogger` is instanciated.
So you can do the following:

```
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void Foo()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Service>().ToSelf();

        kernel.Bind<Logger>().ToSelf()
            .OnActivation((ctx, logger) =>
                logger.Initalize(ctx.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType));

        var service = kernel.Get<Service>();

        service.Logger.RootService.Should().Be(typeof(Service));
    }
}

public class Logger
{
    public Type RootService { get; private set; }

    public void Initalize(Type rootService)
    {
        this.RootService = rootService;
    }
}

public class Service
{
    public Logger Logger { get; private set; }

    public Service(Logger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

However, `IContext` does not provide access to the "parent" instance, so you can only access the type it's injected into, but not the instance.

Also, if that should be enough, there's no need to actually use the `OnActivation` extension, you should also be able to just do it like this:

```
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void Foo()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Service>().ToSelf();

        kernel.Bind<Logger>().ToSelf()
            .WithConstructorArgument(
                typeof(Type),
                ctx => ctx.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType);

        var service = kernel.Get<Service>();

        service.Logger.RootService.Should().Be(typeof(Service));
    }
}

public class Logger
{
    private readonly Type _rootService;

    public Logger(Type rootService)
    {
        _rootService = rootService;
    }

    public Type RootService
    {
        get { return _rootService; }
    }
}

public class Service
{
    public Logger Logger { get; private set; }

    public Service(Logger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, actually it is indeed enough to have the type, wouldn't even be a good practice to have cross-references with the service and the logger. I will use simply the type name or some custom attributes on the service type if I need bigger flexibility.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási You're welcome. Side note: in case you directly request the `Logger` by `kernel.Get<Logger>()` the code i provided will throw an `Exception` because `ctx.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType` is not available. You can add a null-check and special case handling if that is needed.